# Jquery Getting Value From FIrst Dropdown In A Loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am having a popup and a  `foreach` on my view , it has a dropdown too, on a button click I need to get the selected value of the drop-down,

Each time I click it returns the first drop down value
I couldn't use `$(this).val()`

Is there any way.
This is my code

```js
$( ".ecg_followup_submit" ).click(function(e) {

   alert($( ".reviewoutcome_change option:selected" ).val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Review outcome:</label>                                                                
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control reviewoutcome_change" name="review_outcome" id="declined_reason">
          <option value="select">Select</option>
          <option value="normal">Normal</option>
          <option value="minor" >Minor</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="height:10px;"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer" style = "margin-top:15px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ecg_followup_submit" name="Submit" style = "width:50%; height:35px; margin-right:150px;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have removed the unwanted codes

Thank you

Comment: It seems like your code already works. There is one dropdown and its selected value is shown in the alert.

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of 'selected' option you do not need to use :selected. you can get the selected value like any other input. `$('your selector').val()`

However, if you do not change your selection, the first option will be selected by default.

Here is an example inspired from your code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log($('.reviewoutcome_change').val());
  
  
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control reviewoutcome_change" name="review_outcome" id="declined_reason">
  <option value="select">Select</option>
  <option value="normal">Normal</option>
  <option value="minor">Minor</option>
</select>

<button class="btn">show selected</button>
```

Comment: no didnt work 
its on a pop up and on a loop

Comment: please give a snippet of your actual code, it will help to inspect the problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

Find one common ancestor. I assume that you have multiple rows then?

```js
$(".ecg_followup_submit").click(function (e) {
    const row = $(this).closest(".row")
    const selectedOption = row.find(".reviewoutcome_change");
    alert(selectedOption.val());
});
```

Comment: it retuens undefined

Comment: if you use ``row.find(".reviewoutcome_change");`` instead like @kurnia336 suggested?

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
$( ".ecg_followup_submit" ).click(function(e) {
    
    alert($( ".reviewoutcome_change option:selected" ).val());
   
});
```

to this

```
$( ".ecg_followup_submit" ).click(function(e) {
    
    alert($( '.reviewoutcome_change' ).val());
   
});
```

Comment: no didnt work 
its on a pop up and on a loop

Comment: full code pls :") cz i still not get what u want